# JavaScript: Displaying and updating text arrays

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to put a paragraph together on canvas with JavaScript from multiple user specified variables. I start off with...

```
function special01() {
    //clean slate       
    ctxx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.width, ctx.height);

    //navigations important
    drawNav();

   //lets begin

    var newSlate = "You're feeling colorChoice today!";
    document.getElementById("displayed").innerHTML = 
        newSlate;
    if (user.color == 'blue') {
    var array = newSlate.replace("colorChoice", "blue")
    }
    else if (user.color == 'red') {
    etc..etc..
    };
}
```

I seem to be forgetting something, and being just a hobbyist, I'm not sure what.  Essentially I'm just trying to replace `colorChoice` with `blue` when `blue` has been selected by the user.  The selection and `user.color` is updating correctly when selected.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
function special01(){  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.width, ctx.height);
  drawNav();
  document.getElementById('displayed').innerHTML = 'You\'re feeling ' + user.color + ' today!';
}
```

**EDIT**

If you really want to replace substring in a string, this is how you can do it

```
var yourString = 'You\'re feel colorChoice today.';
var user.color = 'blue'; // For example
var newString = yourString.split('colorChoice').join(user.color); // 'You\'re feel blue today.'
```

Comment: I can do that however since it will continue with text dependent upon which  color was selected I was just going to use if/else to replace keywords within the sentence.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @lira153. I edited answer. Is this what you are looking for?